# Why monads? How does it resolve side-effects?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am learning Haskell and trying to understand Monads. I have two questions:

1. From what I understand, Monad is just another typeclass that declares ways to interact with data inside "containers", including `Maybe`, `List`, and `IO`. It seems clever and clean to implement these 3 things with one concept, but really, the point is so there can be clean error handling in a chain of functions, containers, and side effects. Is this a correct interpretation?
2. How exactly is the problem of side-effects solved? With this concept of containers, the language essentially says anything inside the containers is non-deterministic (such as i/o). Because lists and IOs are both containers, lists are equivalence-classed with IO, even though values inside lists seem pretty deterministic to me. So what is deterministic and what has side-effects? I can't wrap my head around the idea that a basic value is deterministic, until you stick it in a container (which is no special than the same value with some other values next to it, e.g. `Nothing`) and it can now be random.

Can someone explain how, intuitively, Haskell gets away with changing state with inputs and output? I'm not seeing the magic here.

Comment: This series might be useful for you, it's talking CPS but the I think the function aspects of it apply here as well.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/continuation+passing+style/

Comment: You're assuming a lot about what monads are supposed to be. But they are far more general than that, and pretty much everything you name is just a specific application of the general concept. Not all monads are nondeterministic, not all monads revolve around side effects, etc. Read http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/What_a_Monad_is_not

Comment: It doesn't help to know what it's not. In fact, I haven't seen many examples of Monads beyond IO and Maybe. It's nice that these were implemented with language features, but what are its other uses beyond IO? If a book dedicates half its pages on Monads, there must be something useful about them.

Comment: That question is valid itself, but different from what you asked. There's `Reader`, `Writer`, `State`, `[]` (list), continuations, various monads for parsing, monads for creating HTML/JS/CSS in web applications, and probably many more. Besides, I'd argue that it does help to understand what monads aren't - you won't see the full power of computers when you're convinced their sole use is doing arithmetic quicker ;)

Answer (score 41):

> The point is so there can be clean error handling in a chain of functions, containers, and side effects. Is this a correct interpretation?

Not really.  You've mentioned a lot of concepts that people cite when trying to explain monads, including side effects, error handling and non-determinism, but it sounds like you've gotten the incorrect sense that all of these concepts apply to all monads.  But there's one concept you mentioned that does: **chaining**.

There are two different flavors of this, so I'll explain it two different ways: one without side effects, and one with side effects.

## No Side Effects:

Take the following example:

```
addM :: (Monad m, Num a) => m a -> m a -> m a
addM ma mb = do
    a <- ma
    b <- mb
    return (a + b)
```

This function adds two numbers, with the twist that they are wrapped in some monad.  Which monad?  Doesn't matter!  In all cases, that special `do` syntax de-sugars to the following:

```
addM ma mb =
    ma >>= \a ->
    mb >>= \b ->
    return (a + b)
```

... or, with operator precedence made explicit:

```
ma >>= (\a -> mb >>= (\b -> return (a + b)))
```

Now you can really see that this is a chain of little functions, all composed together, and its behavior will depend on how `>>=` and `return` are defined for each monad.  If you're familiar with polymorphism in object-oriented languages, this is essentially the same thing: one common interface with multiple implementations.  It's slightly more mind-bending than your average OOP interface, since the interface represents a *computation policy* rather than, say, an animal or a shape or something.

Okay, let's see some examples of how `addM` behaves across different monads.  The `Identity` monad is a decent place to start, since its definition is trivial:

```
instance Monad Identity where
    return a = Identity a  -- create an Identity value
    (Identity a) >>= f = f a  -- apply f to a
```

So what happens when we say:

```
addM (Identity 1) (Identity 2)
```

Expanding this, step by step:

```
(Identity 1) >>= (\a -> (Identity 2) >>= (\b -> return (a + b)))
(\a -> (Identity 2) >>= (\b -> return (a + b)) 1
(Identity 2) >>= (\b -> return (1 + b))
(\b -> return (1 + b)) 2
return (1 + 2)
Identity 3
```

Great.  Now, since you mentioned clean error handling, let's look at the `Maybe` monad.  Its definition is only slightly trickier than `Identity`:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return a = Just a  -- same as Identity monad!
    (Just a) >>= f = f a  -- same as Identity monad again!
    Nothing >>= _ = Nothing  -- the only real difference from Identity
```

So you can imagine that if we say `addM (Just 1) (Just 2)` we'll get `Just 3`.  But for grins, let's expand `addM Nothing (Just 1)` instead:

```
Nothing >>= (\a -> (Just 1) >>= (\b -> return (a + b)))
Nothing
```

Or the other way around, `addM (Just 1) Nothing`:

```
(Just 1) >>= (\a -> Nothing >>= (\b -> return (a + b)))
(\a -> Nothing >>= (\b -> return (a + b)) 1
Nothing >>= (\b -> return (1 + b))
Nothing
```

So the `Maybe` monad's definition of `>>=` was tweaked to account for failure.  When a function is applied to a `Maybe` value using `>>=`, you get what you'd expect.

Okay, so you mentioned non-determinism.  Yes, the list monad can be thought of as modeling non-determinism in a sense...  It's a little weird, but think of the list as representing alternative possible values: `[1, 2, 3]` is not a collection, it's a single non-deterministic number that could be either one, two or three.  That sounds dumb, but it starts to make some sense when you think about how `>>=` is defined for lists: it applies the given function to each possible value.  So `addM [1, 2] [3, 4]` is actually going to compute all possible sums of those two non-deterministic values: `[4, 5, 5, 6]`.

Okay, now to address your second question...

## Side Effects:

Let's say you apply `addM` to two values in the `IO` monad, like:

```
addM (return 1 :: IO Int) (return 2 :: IO Int)
```

You don't get anything special, just 3 in the `IO` monad.  `addM` does not read or write any mutable state, so it's kind of no fun.  Same goes for the `State` or `ST` monads.  No fun.  So let's use a different function:

```
fireTheMissiles :: IO Int  -- returns the number of casualties
```

Clearly the world will be different each time missiles are fired.  Clearly.  Now let's say you're trying to write some totally innocuous, side effect free, non-missile-firing code.  Perhaps you're trying once again to add two numbers, but this time without any monads flying around:

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add a b = a + b
```

and all of a sudden your hand slips, and you accidentally typo:

```
add a b = a + b + fireTheMissiles
```

An honest mistake, really.  The keys were so close together.  Fortunately, because `fireTheMissiles` was of type `IO Int` rather than simply `Int`, the compiler is able to avert disaster.

Okay, totally contrived example, but the point is that in the case of `IO`, `ST` and friends, the type system keeps effects isolated to some specific context.  It doesn't magically eliminate side effects, making code referentially transparent that shouldn't be, but it does make it clear at compile time what scope the effects are limited to.

So getting back to the original point: what does this have to do with chaining or composition of functions?  Well, in this case, it's just a handy way of expressing a sequence of effects:

```
fireTheMissilesTwice :: IO ()
fireTheMissilesTwice = do
    a <- fireTheMissiles
    print a
    b <- fireTheMissiles
    print b
```

## Summary:

A monad represents some policy for chaining computations.  `Identity`'s policy is pure function composition, `Maybe`'s policy is function composition with failure propogation, `IO`'s policy is *impure* function composition and so on.

Comment: `main = forever fireTheMissiles` considered harmful.

Answer (score 11):

You could see a given monad `m` as a set/family (or realm, domain, etc.) of *actions* (think of a C statement). The monad `m` defines the kind of (side-)effects that its actions may have:

- with `[]` you can define actions which can fork their executions in different "independent parallel worlds";
- with `Either Foo` you can define actions which can fail with errors of type `Foo`;
- with `IO` you can define actions which can have side-effects on the "outside world" (access files, network, launch processes, do a HTTP GET ...);
- you can have a monad whose effect is "randomness" (see package `MonadRandom`);
- you can define a monad whose actions can make a move in a game (say chess, Go…) and receive move from an opponent but are not able to write to your filesystem or anything else.

### Summary

If `m` is a monad, `m a` is an *action* which produces a result/output of type `a`.

The `>>` and `>>=` operators are used to create more complex actions out of simpler ones:

- `a >> b` is a macro-action which does action `a` and then action `b`;
- `a >> a` does action `a` and then action `a` again;
- with `>>=` the second action can depend on the output of the first one.

The exact meaning of what an *action* is and what *doing an action and then another one* is depends on the monad: each monad defines an imperative sublanguage with some features/effects.

### Simple sequencing (`>>`)

Let's say with have a given monad `M` and some *actions* `incrementCounter`, `decrementCounter`, `readCounter`:

```
instance M Monad where ...

-- Modify the counter and do not produce any result:
incrementCounter :: M ()
decrementCounter :: M ()

-- Get the current value of the counter
readCounter :: M Integer
```

Now we would like to do something interesting with those actions. The first thing we would like to do with those actions is to sequence them. As in say C, we would like to be able to do:

```
// This is C:
counter++;
counter++;
```

We define an "sequencing operator" `>>`. Using this operator we can write:

```
incrementCounter >> incrementCounter
```

What is the type of "incrementCounter >> incrementCounter"?

1. It is an action made of two smaller actions like in C you can write composed-statements from atomic statements :

   ```
   // This is a macro statement made of several statements
   {
     counter++;
     counter++;
   }

   // and we can use it anywhere we may use a statement:
   if (condition) {
      counter++;
      counter++;     
   }
   ```
2. it can have the same kind of effects as its subactions;
3. it does not produce any output/result.

So we would like `incrementCounter >> incrementCounter` to be of type `M ()`: an (macro-)action with the same kind of possible effects but without any output.

More generally, given two actions:

```
action1 :: M a
action2 :: M b
```

we define a `a >> b` as the macro-action which is obtained by *doing* (whatever that means in our domain of action) `a` then `b` and produces as output the result of the execution of the second action. The type of `>>` is:

```
(>>) :: M a -> M b -> M b
```

or more generally:

```
(>>) :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b -> m b
```

We can define bigger sequence of actions from simpler ones:

```
 action1 >> action2 >> action3 >> action4
```

### Input and outputs (`>>=`)

We would like to be able to increment by something else that 1 at a time:

```
incrementBy 5
```

We want to provide some input in our actions, in order to do this we define a function `incrementBy` taking an `Int` and producing an action:

```
incrementBy :: Int -> M ()
```

Now we can write things like:

```
incrementCounter >> readCounter >> incrementBy 5
```

But we have no way to feed the output of `readCounter` into `incrementBy`. In order to do this, a slightly more powerful version of our sequencing operator is needed. The `>>=` operator can feed the output of a given action as input to the next action. We can write:

```
readCounter >>= incrementBy
```

It is an action which executes the `readCounter` action, feeds its output in the `incrementBy` function and then execute the resulting action.

The type of `>>=` is:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

### A (partial) example

Let's say I have a `Prompt` monad which can only display informations (text) to the user and ask informations to the user:

```
-- We don't have access to the internal structure of the Prompt monad
module Prompt (Prompt(), echo, prompt) where

-- Opaque
data Prompt a = ...
instance Monad Prompt where ...

-- Display a line to the CLI:
echo :: String -> Prompt ()

-- Ask a question to the user:
prompt :: String -> Prompt String
```

Let's try to define a `promptBoolean message` actions which asks for a question and produces a boolean value.

We use the prompt `(message ++ "[y/n]")` action and feed its output to a function `f`:

- `f "y"` should be an action which does nothing but produce `True` as output;
- `f "n"` should be an action which does nothing but produce `False` as output;
- anything else should restart the action (do the action again);

`promptBoolean` would look like this:

```
    -- Incomplete version, some bits are missing:
    promptBoolean :: String -> M Boolean
    promptBoolean message = prompt (message ++ "[y/n]") >>= f
      where f result = if result == "y"
                       then ???? -- We need here an action which does nothing but produce `True` as output
                       else if result=="n"
                            then ???? -- We need here an action which does nothing but produce `False` as output
                            else echo "Input not recognised, try again." >> promptBoolean
```

### Producing a value without effect (`return`)

In order to fill the missing bits in our `promptBoolean` function, we need a way to represent dummy actions without any side effect but which only outputs a given value:

```
-- "return 5" is an action which does nothing but outputs 5
return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
```

and we can now write out `promptBoolean` function:

```
promptBoolean :: String -> Prompt Boolean
promptBoolean message :: prompt (message ++ "[y/n]") >>= f
  where f result = if result=="y"
                   then return True
                     else if result=="n"
                     then return False
                     else echo "Input not recognised, try again." >> promptBoolean message
```

By composing those two simple actions (`promptBoolean`, `echo`) we can define any kind of dialogue between the user and your program (the actions of the program are deterministic as our monad does not have a "randomness effect").

```
promptInt :: String -> M Int
promptInt = ... -- similar

-- Classic "guess a number game/dialogue"
guess :: Int -> m()
guess n = promptInt "Guess:" m -> f
   where f m = if m == n
               then echo "Found"
               else (if m > n
                     then echo "Too big"
                     then echo "Too small") >> guess n
```

### The operations of a monad

A Monad is a set of actions which can be composed with the `return` and `>>=` operators:

- `>>=` for action composition;
- `return` for producing a value without any (side-)effect.

These two operators are the minimal operators needed to define a `Monad`.

In Haskell, the `>>` operator is needed as well but it can in fact be derived from `>>=`:

```
(>>): Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
a >> b = a >>= f
 where f x = b
```

In Haskell, an extra `fail` operator is need as well but this is really a hack (and [it might be removed from `Monad` in the future](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/monad_fail.md)).

This is the Haskell definition of a `Monad`:

```
class Monad m where     
  return :: m a     
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b     
  (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b  -- can be derived from (>>=)
  fail :: String -> m a      -- mostly a hack
```

### Actions are first-class

One great thing about monads is that actions are first-class. You can take them in a variable, you can define function which take actions as input and produce some other actions as output. For example, we can define a `while` operator:

```
-- while x y : does action y while action x output True
while :: (Monad m) => m Boolean -> m a -> m ()
while x y = x >>= f
  where f True = y >> while x y
        f False = return ()
```

### Summary

A `Monad` is a set of *actions* in some domain. The monad/domain define the kind of "effects" which are possible. The `>>` and `>>=` operators represent sequencing of actions and monadic expression may be used to represent any kind of "imperative (sub)program" in your (functional) Haskell program.

The great things are that:

- you can design your own `Monad` which supports the features and effects that you want

  - see `Prompt` for an example of a "dialogue only subprogram",
  - see `Rand` for an example of "sampling only subprogram";
- you can write your own control structures (`while`, `throw`, `catch` or more exotic ones) as functions taking actions and composing them in some way to produce a bigger macro-actions.

### `MonadRandom`

A good way of understanding monads, is the `MonadRandom` package. The `Rand` monad is made of actions whose output can be random (the effect is randomness). An *action* in this monad is some kind of random variable (or more exactly a sampling process):

```
 -- Sample an Int from some distribution
 action :: Rand Int
```

Using `Rand` to do some sampling/random algorithms is quite interesting because you have *random variables* as first class values:

```
-- Estimate mean by sampling nsamples times the random variable x
sampleMean :: Real a => Int -> m a -> m a
sampleMean n x = ...
```

In this setting, the `sequence` function from `Prelude`,

```
 sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

becomes

```
 sequence :: [Rand a] -> Rand [a]
```

It creates a random variable obtained by sampling independently from a list of random variables.

Answer (score 10):

Let me start by pointing at the excellent "[You could have invented monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)" article. It illustrates how the Monad structure can naturally manifest while you are writing programs. But the tutorial doesn't mention `IO`, so I will have a stab here at extending the approach.

Let us start with what you probably have already seen - the container monad. Let's say we have:

```
f, g :: Int -> [Int]
```

One way of looking at this is that it gives us a number of possible outputs for every possible input. What if we want all possible outputs for the *composition* of both functions? Giving all possibilities we could get by applying the functions one after the other?

Well, there's a function for that:

```
fg x = concatMap g $ f x
```

If we put this more general, we get

```
fg x     = f x >>= g
xs >>= f = concatMap f xs
return x = [x]
```

Why would we want to wrap it like this? Well, writing our programs primarily using `>>=` and `return` gives us some nice properties - for example, we can be sure that it's relatively hard to "forget" solutions. We'd explicitly have to reintroduce it, say by adding another function `skip`. And also we now have a monad and can use all combinators from the monad library!

Now, let us jump to your trickier example. Let's say the two functions are "side-effecting". That's not non-deterministic, it just means that in theory the whole world is both their input (as it can influence them) as well as their output (as the function can influence it). So we get something like:

```
f, g :: Int -> RealWorld# -> (Int, RealWorld#)
```

If we now want `f` to get the world that `g` left behind, we'd write:

```
fg x rw = let (y, rw')  = f x rw
              (r, rw'') = g y rw'
           in (r, rw'')
```

Or generalized:

```
fg x     = f x >>= g
x >>= f  = \rw -> let (y, rw')  = x   rw
                      (r, rw'') = f y rw'
                   in (r, rw'')
return x = \rw -> (x, rw)
```

Now if the user can only use `>>=`, `return` and a few pre-defined `IO` values we get a nice property again: The user will never actually *see* the `RealWorld#` getting passed around! And that is a very good thing, as you aren't really interested in the details of where `getLine` gets its data from. And *again* we get all the nice high-level functions from the monad libraries.

So the important things to take away:

1. The monad captures common patterns in your code, like "always pass all elements of container A to container B" or "pass this real-world-tag through". Often, once you realize that there is a monad in your program, complicated things become simply applications of the right monad combinator.
2. The monad allows you to *completely* hide the implementation from the user. It is an excellent encapsulation mechanism, be it for your own internal state or for how `IO` manages to squeeze non-purity into a pure program in a relatively safe way.

---

**Appendix**

In case someone is still scratching his head over `RealWorld#` as much as I did when I started: There's obviously more magic going on *after* all the monad abstraction has been removed. Then the compiler will make use of the fact that there can only ever be one "real world". That's good news and bad news:

1. It follows that the compiler *must* guarantuee execution ordering between functions (which is what we were after!)
2. But it also means that actually passing the real world isn't necessary as there is only one we could possibly mean: The one that is current when the function gets executed!

Bottom line is that once execution order is fixed, `RealWorld#` simply gets optimized out. Therefore programs using the `IO` monad actually have zero runtime overhead. Also note that using `RealWorld#` is obviously only *one* possible way to put `IO` - but it happens to be the one GHC uses internally. The good thing about monads is that, again, the user really doesn't need to know.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you, Peter! To summarize in my own words, just for kicks, monads allow passing around of a hidden context that callers do not have to see or use. Side-effects are achieved by passing around a compiler generated "real world" context that is modified (IO input/output) on each succession of an IO call.

Comment: Yes - such contexts are both one of the easiest and most useful applications to know. But to be fair, there are many other "patterns" that can be captured that don't have much to do with passing around contexts - for example the exception monad encapsulating the "do `x` and only if it doesn't fail continue with `y`" pattern by making `Maybe a` a monad. The translation is actually quite straightforward - I encourage you to try it yourself or look it up.

Answer (score 5):

There are three main observations concerning the IO monad:

1) You can't get values out of it. Other types like `Maybe` might allow to extract values, but neither the monad class interface itself nor the `IO` data type allow it.

2) "Inside" `IO` is not only the real value but also that "RealWorld" thing. This dummy value is used to enforce the chaining of actions *by the type system*: If you have two independent calculations, the use of `>>=` makes the second calculation dependent on the first.

3) Assume a non-deterministic thing like `random :: () -> Int`, which isn't allowed in Haskell. If you change the signature to `random :: Blubb -> (Blubb, Int)`, it *is* allowed, if you make sure that nobody ever can use a `Blubb` twice: Because in that case all inputs are "different", it is no problem that the outputs are different as well.

Now we can use the fact 1): Nobody can get something out of `IO`, so we can use the `RealWord` dummy hidden in `IO` to serve as a `Blubb`. There is only one `IO`in the whole application (the one we get from `main`), and it takes care of proper sequentiation, as we have seen in 2). Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that often helps me to understand the nature of something is to examine it in the most trivial way possible. That way, I'm not getting distracted by potentially unrelated concepts. With that in mind, I think it may be helpful to understand the nature of the [Identity Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Identity.html), as it's the most trivial implementation of a Monad possible (I think).

What is interesting about the Identity Monad? I think it is that it allows me to express the idea of evaluating expressions in a context defined by other expressions. And to me, that is the essence of every Monad I've encountered (so far).

If you already had a lot of exposure to 'mainstream' programming languages before learning Haskell (like I did), then this doesn't seem very interesting at all. After all, in a mainstream programming language, statements are executed in sequence, one after the other (excepting control-flow constructs, of course). And naturally, we can assume that every statement is evaluated in the context of all previously executed statements and that those previously executed statements may alter the environment and the behavior of the currently executing statement.

All of that is pretty much a foreign concept in a functional, lazy language like Haskell. The order in which computations are evaluated in Haskell is well-defined, but sometimes hard to predict, and even harder to control. And for many kinds of problems, that's just fine. But other sorts of problems (e.g. IO) are hard to solve without some convenient way to establish an implicit order and context between the computations in your program.

As far as side-effects go, specifically, often they can be transformed (via a Monad) in to simple state-passing, which is perfectly legal in a pure functional language. Some Monads don't seem to be of that nature, however. Monads such as the IO Monad or the ST monad literally perform side-effecting actions. There are many ways to think about this, but one way that I think about it is that just because my computations must exist in a world without side-effects, the Monad may not. As such, the Monad is free to establish a context for my computation to execute that is based on side-effects defined by other computations.

Finally, I must disclaim that I am definitely not a Haskell expert. As such, please understand that everything I've said is pretty much my own thoughts on this subject and I may very well disown them later when I understand Monads more fully.

Comment: The most trivial monad is probably the crapy monad: data Crappy a = Crappy. But is it not very useful.

Comment: I like how this answer complements Peter's. Let me know if I'm understanding this perspective right: instead of our program modifying the world by calling some special API (e.g. C's <stdio.h>), it's more like we define functions that are free of side-effects, and have them get called by a set of APIs (IO monads) that pass to these functions different things depending on user/file/network input. (That makes everything we program in Haskell deterministic, because the language itself restricts us from defining anything that modifies IO.)

Comment: @MTsoul Yes, I think you understand that point of view at least as well as I do :). I find that the #RealWorld state-passing perspective is both interesting and instructive, but it seems that many hard-core Haskellers have a dislike for that explanation because it focuses on (what amounts to) an implementation detail. By the way, I find that the explanation given by ysdx is another good perspective because from inside a pure computation, side-effects are modelled as values describing actions to be performed (as opposed to actually performing the action).

Answer (score 3):

> With this concept of containers, the language essentially says anything inside the containers is non-deterministic

No. Haskell is deterministic. If you ask for integer addition 2+2 you will always get 4.

"Nondeterministic" is only a metaphor, a way of thinking. Everything is deterministic under the hood. If you have this code:

```
do x <- [4,5]
   y <- [0,1]
   return (x+y)
```

it is roughly equivalent to Python code

```
 l = []
 for x in [4,5]:
     for y in [0,1]:
         l.append(x+y)
```

You see nondeterminism here? No, it's deterministic construction of a list. Run it twice, you'll get the same numbers in the same order.

You can describe it this way: Choose arbitrary x from [4,5]. Choose arbitrary y from [0,1]. Return x+y. Collect all possible results.

That way seems to involve nondeterminism, but it's only a nested loop (list comprehension). There is no "real" nondeterminism here, it's simulated by checking all possibilities. Nondeterminism is an illusion. The code only appears to be nondeterministic.

This code using State monad:

```
do put 0
   x <- get
   put (x+2)
   y <- get
   return (y+3)
```

gives 5 and seems to involve changing state. As with lists it's an illusion. There are no "variables" that change (as in imperative languages). Everything is nonmutable under the hood.

You can describe the code this way: put 0 to a variable. Read the value of a variable to x. Put (x+2) to the variable. Read the variable to y, and return y+3.

That way seems to involve state, but it's only composing functions passing additional parameter. There is no "real" mutability here, it's simulated by composition. Mutability is an illusion. The code only appears to be using it.

Haskell does it this way: you've got functions

```
   a -> s -> (b,s)
```

This function takes and old value of state and returns new value. It does not involve mutability or change variables. It's a function in mathematical sense.

For example the function "put" takes new value of state, ignores current state and returns new state:

```
   put x _ = ((), x)
```

Just like you can compose two normal functions

```
  a -> b
  b -> c
```

into

```
  a -> c
```

using (.) operator you can compose "state" transformers

```
  a -> s -> (b,s)
  b -> s -> (c,s)
```

into a single function

```
  a -> s -> (c,s)
```

Try writing the composition operator yourself. This is what really happens, there are no "side effects" only passing arguments to functions.

Answer (score 2):

> the point is so there can be clean error handling in a chain of functions, containers, and side effects

More or less.

> how exactly is the problem of side-effects solved?

A value in the I/O monad, i.e. one of type `IO a`, should be interpreted as a program. `p >> q` on `IO` values can then be interpreted as the operator that combines two programs into one that first executes `p`, then `q`. The other monad operators have similar interpretations. By assigning a program to the name `main`, you declare to the compiler that that is the program that has to be executed by its output object code.

As for the list monad, it's not really related to the I/O monad except in a very abstract mathematical sense. The `IO` monad gives deterministic computation with side effects, while the list monad gives non-deterministic (but not random!) backtracking search, somewhat similar to Prolog's modus operandi.

Comment: Right, >> and >>= give sequence to functions/monads. I may be confusing determinism with side-effects, but it still doesn't explain how (and why it's allowed that) IO can return different values at different times, vs list always returning the same result. (That's determinism, right?)

Comment: One way to think about it: the IO monad effectively takes the state of the world before the I/O operation as an implicit argument, and implicitly returns the state of the world after the I/O operation.  So, the operations return different results because they are operating on successive states of the world...

Comment: @larsmans: can I interpret that, with chaining functions in succession, input to the program is delayed and split into chunks (getLine takes in input when it's called), and that's what Monads achieves? By sequencing functions and getting the value when it's needed?

Comment: @MTsoul: I guess you could view it like that, but then C's `getchar` could be viewed in the same way. `c = getchar(); printf("Hello, world!\n");` delays the printing until after the `getchar` is completed. Haskell's `>>` is little more than adjoining two statements in C.

Comment: Here's an illuminating blogpost on how IO monad came to be: http://r6.ca/blog/20110520T220201Z.html

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, `Monad` is just another typeclass that declares ways to interact with data [...]

...providing an *interface* common to all those types which have an instance. This can then be used to provide generic definitions which work across all monadic types.

> It seems clever and clean to implement these 3 things with one concept [...]

...the only three things that are implemented are the *instances* for those three types (list, `Maybe` and `IO`) - the types themselves are defined independently elsewhere.

> [...] but really, the point is so there can be clean error handling in a chain of functions, containers, and side effects.

Not just error handling e.g. consider `ST` - without the monadic interface, *you* would have to pass the encapsulated-state directly **and** correctly...a tiresome task.

---

> How exactly is the problem of side-effects solved?

Short answer: Haskell <s>solves</s> manages them by using types to indicate their presence.

> Can someone explain how, intuitively, Haskell gets away with changing state with inputs and output?

"Intuitively"...like what's available [over here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_tutorials_timeline)? Let's try a simple direct comparison instead:

- From [How to Declare an Imperative](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.3579&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Philip Wadler:

  ```
  (* page 26 *)
  type 'a io  = unit -> 'a

  infix >>=
  val >>=     : 'a io * ('a -> 'b io) -> 'b io
  fun m >>= k = fn () => let
                           val x = m ()
                           val y = k x ()
                         in
                           y
                         end

  val return  : 'a -> 'a io
  fun return x = fn () => x

  val putc    : char -> unit io
  fun putc c = fn () => putcML c

  val getc    : char io
  val getc  = fn () => getcML ()

  fun getcML () =
     valOf(TextIO.input1(TextIO.stdIn))

  (* page 25 *)
  fun putcML c =
    TextIO.output1(TextIO.stdOut,c)
  ```
- Based on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63315104/13679816) two [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64365219/13679816) of mine, this is my Haskell translation:

  ```
  type IO a  =  OI -> a

  (>>=)      :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
  m >>= k    =  \ u -> let !(u1, u2) = part u in
                       let !x = m u1 in
                       let !y = k x u2 in
                       y

  return     :: a -> IO a
  return x   =  \ u -> let !_ = part u in x

  putc       :: Char -> IO ()
  putc c     =  \ u -> putcOI c u

  getc       :: IO Char
  getc       =  \ u -> getcOI u

   -- primitives
  data OI
  partOI :: OI -> (OI, OI) 
  putcOI :: Char -> OI -> ()
  getcOI :: OI -> Char
  ```

Now remember that short answer about side-effects?

*Haskell manages them by using types to indicate their presence.*

```
Data.Char.chr :: Int -> Char    -- no side effects

getChar       :: IO Char        -- side effects at
           {- :: OI -> Char -}  -- work: beware!
```